# How to hide the vertical gridlines of the group header in betterlistview control?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, better-listview

I'm using the betterlistview control in my .net application. I need help regarding gridlines when used with groups. I'm using the details view, and the gridlines property is set to "grid". I have also groups added to list. The problem is that vertical grid lines are also displayed alongside the group header area which makes the groups look a little less elegant and also less clear. Also the first row item of the group does not display the upper horizontal gridline. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a snapshot of the listview I'm working on:

[image: Betterlistview with gridlines and groups]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much struggle, I finally emailed the Component Owl (company that developed betterlistview control) support team and got a quick reply. I hope it might help someone, so I am quoting the answer here from Mr. Libor Tinka (Chief Developer, ComponentOwl.com) :

"This is not supported ot of the box, but the unwanted grid lines can be erased using custom drawing. Simply subclass BetterListView and add OnDrawGroup method override:

```
protected override void OnDrawGroup(BetterListViewDrawGroupEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    eventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, eventArgs.GroupBounds.BoundsInner);
    base.OnDrawGroup(eventArgs);
}
```

Note that base.OnDrawGroup is called after custom drawing. This ensures we won't replace text, images and other features of the group header.

The result looks like this:"

[image]